# Two Google Analtyics profiles in same same tracking script not working

Tags: google-analytics, seo

We have two profiles that we are tracking for the same site and only one account is working.

Getting the following error in the second GA profile, but I've confirmed code is correct:

> Property `http://www.ourwebsite.com` is not receiving hits. Either your
>   site is not receiving any sessions or it is not tagged correctly.

Is there anything wrong with this?

Here's the following code I'm using:

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-########-1', 'auto');
      ga('create', 'UA-########-1', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker'});
      ga('send', 'pageview');
      ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: That code looks correct, according to Google's developer reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#named

Are you sure your properties are both configured correctly in Analytics?

Comment: Is this code live anywhere? If you provide a link I can confirm whether or not it's working.

Comment: @Philip Walton, I'd rather not make domain name public. I'm happy to send to you in a private message, however. Please let me know...

Comment: @frshjb373 sure, message/email me.